# writeAndFlush method not working for ByteBuf

Tags: android, netty, nio

At first, I had trouble sending any kind of data using `writeAndFlush(...)` until I stumbled upon this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934777/netty-writeandflush-method-doesnt-work-solved). Now, I can already send `Strings` from the server to the client using the `writeAndFlush(...)` with the suffix */r/n* for every string. The issue remains when I try to send a `ByteBuf` object. Obviously, I can't just add */r/n* to the end of the message. Any solution for this?

I'm using `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` if it helps.

Comment: I can't see why these control characters should be neccessary. could you take a look at the answers that were given at the link you provided and check if an exception occurs?

Comment: For added context, the platform is Android which, according to docs of 4.1, is already supported. I examined the mobile device in runtime using _adb logcat_ and found no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ctx.channel().write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(byteDataToTransfer));
ctx.channel().flush();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'll try this one. Still, I find it strange that _writeAndFlush_ is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

writeAndFlush(...) should just work fine. Please check the status of the returned ChannelFuture and see if it was failed or not.

Comment: It's firing the _operationComplete_ event successfully. Check the link I provided and see the strange behavior of _writeAndFlush_.

Comment: what is the "strange behavior" ?

Comment: The fact that you need to add _\r\n_. But I figured out that it might be because of the declared: _Delimiters.lineDelimeter()_.